# Override gradient from upper div Calendar

Tags: calendar, zimbra

I need to remove the gradient in the calendar's appointment and I can't find the gradient attribute ( search every where ) So I though may be I can like disable it or override it from the above div but the problem is I don't know the color of the gradient because the user can change the appointment color ( shared calendar ) ...

Does anyone know a bit about this ?

Zimbra 8.0.9

Answer (score 0):

unzip and edit the script : Startup1_1_all.js.zgz

```
cd /opt/zimbra/jetty/webapps/zimbra/js
gunzip -S zgz Startup1_1_all.js.zgz
vim Startup1_1_all.js.
```

add "s=t;" at the beggining of the function "createLinearGradientInfo"

save the file and zip it

```
gzip -S zgz Startup1_1_all.js.
```

Have a good day.